# can the database definition be updated with simple changes in the Class in Java Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Using Java and hibernate, I was wondering that if I can change the Database definition after creation, just by making changes to my existing Entity Class. Will the Changes be reflected in the Database??? Is it Possible??? I tried and Failed. I have tried

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

But getting error, if it is still possible, here is my code.

```
/**
 * Description of bankbranchcontactdetailsBean
 *
 * @author Vishal Jain @ TurtleTec Inc.
 */
package com.beans;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity(name = "bankbranchcontactdetails")
@Table(name = "bankbranchcontactdetails", schema = "stserptest", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "BankBranchContactId") })
@TableGenerator(name = "bankbranchcontactdetailsgen", table = "bankbranchcontactdetails", pkColumnName = "BankBranchContactId")
public class bankbranchcontactdetailsBean extends SuperBeanClass implements
        SuperBeanInterface, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "INT(10) UNSIGNED", name = "BankBranchContactId", precision = 10, scale = 0, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer Id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "INT(10) UNSIGNED", name = "BankBranchId", precision = 10, scale = 0, nullable = false)
    private Integer _BankBranchId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('PHONE','MOBILE','FAX','TELEX')", name = "ContactTypeModified", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private String _ContactTypeModified;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20)", name = "Contact", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String _Contact;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "INT(10) UNSIGNED", name = "NewField", precision = 10, scale = 0, nullable = true)
    private Integer _NewField;

    public bankbranchcontactdetailsBean() {

        _BankBranchId = 0;
        _ContactType = "";
        _Contact = "";
        _NewField = 0;
    }

    public bankbranchcontactdetailsBean(Integer __BankBranchId,
            String __ContactTypeModified String __Contact, Integer __MyCompanyId) {

        _BankBranchId = __BankBranchId;
        _ContactTypeModified = __ContactTypeModified;
        _Contact = __Contact;
        _MyCompanyId = __MyCompanyId;
    }

    public int getBankBranchContactId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public Integer getBankBranchId() {
        return _BankBranchId;
    }

    public String getContactType() {
        return _ContactTypeModified;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return _Contact;
    }

    public Integer getNewField() {
        return _NewField;
    }

    public void setBankBranchContactId(int NewValue) {
        Id = NewValue;
    }

    public void setBankBranchId(Integer NewValue) {
        _BankBranchId = NewValue;
    }

    public void setContactType(String NewValue) {
        _ContactTypeModified = NewValue;
    }

    public void setContact(String NewValue) {
        _Contact = NewValue;
    }

    public void setNewField(Integer NewValue) {
        _NewField = NewValue;
    }

}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">V32</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">stserptest</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</property>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.stserp.beans.bankbranchcontactdetailsBean" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>



/**
 * Description of ManagerClass
 *
 * @author Vishal Jain 
 */
package com.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class ManagerClass {

    private static SessionFactory factory = null;
    private static ManagerClass _ManagerClass = null;

    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    public static ManagerClass getInstance() throws ExceptionInInitializerError {
        try {
            if (factory == null) {
                factory = createSessionFactory();
            }
            if (_ManagerClass == null) {
                _ManagerClass = new ManagerClass();
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null,
                    "Failed to create sessionFactory object...\n"
                            + ex.getMessage(), "Error...", 0);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        } finally {
            return _ManagerClass;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> SaveBeansList(Session session, String entityName,
            ArrayList<? extends SuperBeanClass> BeansList)
            throws HibernateException {
        ArrayList<Integer> IDs = null;
        try {
            IDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (SuperBeanClass element : BeansList) {
                IDs.add((Integer) session.save(entityName, element));
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return IDs;
    }

    public ArrayList<? extends SuperBeanClass> LoadTable(Session session,
            String TableName) throws HibernateException {
        ArrayList<? extends SuperBeanClass> beansList = null;
        try {
            beansList = (ArrayList<? extends SuperBeanClass>) session
                    .createQuery("FROM " + TableName).list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return beansList;
    }

    public ArrayList<?> LoadConditional(Session session, String _query)
            throws HibernateException {
        ArrayList<?> beansList = null;
        try {
            beansList = (ArrayList<? extends SuperBeanClass>) session
                    .createQuery(_query).list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return beansList;
    }

    public SuperBeanInterface LoadById(Session session, Class className,
            Integer ID) throws HibernateException {
        SuperBeanInterface BeanInterface = null;
        try {
            BeanInterface = (SuperBeanInterface) session.get(className, ID);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return BeanInterface;
    }

    public void DeleteById(Session session, Class className, Integer ID)
            throws HibernateException {
        try {
            session.delete(session.get(className, ID));
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}




/**
 * Description of SuperBeanClass
 *
 * @author Vishal Jain 
 */
package com.beans;

public class SuperBeanClass {
    public SuperBeanClass() {
    }
}



/**
 * Description of SuperBeanInterface
 *
 * @author Vishal Jain 
 */
package com.beans;

public interface SuperBeanInterface {
}
```

Here the field 'ContactType' has been Changed to 'ContactTypeModified' and a new Field 'NewField' has been added to the Entity Class. No manual changes have been made to the Database. I am getting Error upon the execution of the program which is as Follows :

```
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.6.Final}
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Aug 14, 2014 10:13:59 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: bankbranchcontactdetails
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: bankbranchcontactdetails
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: bankbranchcontactdetails
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table stserptest.bankbranchcontactdetails (BankBranchContactId INT(10) UNSIGNED not null auto_increment, BankBranchId INT(10) UNSIGNED not null, Contact VARCHAR(20) not null, ContactTypeModified ENUM('PHONE','MOBILE','FAX','TELEX') not null, EntryDate TIMESTAMP, MyCompanyId INT(10) UNSIGNED not null, NewField INT(10) UNSIGNED, UserId INT(10) UNSIGNED, isDeleted ENUM('YES','NO'), primary key (BankBranchContactId))
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Table 'bankbranchcontactdetails' already exists
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: bankbranchcontactdetails
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: bankbranchcontactdetails
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: bankbranchcontactdetails
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table stserptest.bankbranchcontactdetails (BankBranchContactId INT(10) UNSIGNED not null auto_increment, BankBranchId INT(10) UNSIGNED not null, Contact VARCHAR(20) not null, ContactTypeModified ENUM('PHONE','MOBILE','FAX','TELEX') not null, EntryDate TIMESTAMP, MyCompanyId INT(10) UNSIGNED not null, NewField INT(10) UNSIGNED, UserId INT(10) UNSIGNED, isDeleted ENUM('YES','NO'), primary key (BankBranchContactId))
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Table 'bankbranchcontactdetails' already exists
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        stserptest.bankbranchcontactdetails
        (BankBranchId, Contact, ContactTypeModified, EntryDate, MyCompanyId, NewField, UserId, isDeleted) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
Aug 14, 2014 10:14:00 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'ContactTypeModified' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate *can* modify the db structure if you set it into update mode

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

However it might be better to use something like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyaway](http://flywaydb.org/) that will keep track of the versioning of the tables over time.

In my experience relying on hibernate to keep the schema in sync with the entity models won't work in the long run, especially if you have any kind of branching in your project.  You would be opening yourself up for dataloss, unless you instruct it on how to mutate the columns to preserve all of the information inside.  Hibernate can very well just choose to drop a column and add a new one, when all you wanted was to rename; this would be bad.

However if you are using an embedded in-memory db (like hsqldb) and do not care about persisting data between executions, then yes you can simply setup hibernate to use the *create* or *create-drop* mode and it will construct the tables to match your entities.